# SQL UPDATE (copy from row to row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, sql-update

I want to try to copy a value from one record in a Table to another record in the same table an same column.

```
    UPDATE
    [PDF]
SET
    [PDF].[description] = [MISC].[description]
FROM (
    SELECT
          [PDF].[TPYE]
         ,[ID]
         ,[PDF].[description]
    FROM [DB1] AS [PDF]
    
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
             [TYPE]
             [description]
             [ID]
        FROM [DB1]
        WHERE [TYPE] = 'MISC'
            ) AS [MISC] ON [PDF].[ID] = [MISC].[ID]
WHERE
    [PDF].[TPYE] = 'PDF'
```

For more clarification ive added a screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixolu.png)

The Table contains a few thousands rows, and i want to copy the description from one row to another - dependent on NUMBER and TYPE.

Comment: Note - tables have *rows*, not *records*.

Comment: Please clarify your problem with more description and let me know what is current table data and desire data

Comment: Do you have _table_ called DB1? Very confusing choice of table name...

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying. You only have one table (DB1), so if you update where id = id, then you are updating nothing. I guess you want to update the description where type = 'PDF' and copy the description of some record with type = 'MISC', but... you need another field to match one record with another, don't you?

Comment: In your screenshot you seem to have a *schema* named `DB1` - very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this as an example.  You were pretty close.

```
DECLARE @DB1 AS TABLE ( ID          INT           NOT NULL
,                       TYPE        NVARCHAR(4)   NOT NULL
,                       Description NVARCHAR(255) NULL )

INSERT INTO @DB1 ( ID, TYPE, Description )
VALUES ( 1, N'PDF', N'' )
,      ( 1, N'MISC', N'Description 1' )
,      ( 2, N'PDF', N'' )
,      ( 2, N'MISC', N'Description 2' )

SELECT  *
  FROM  @DB1
 WHERE  TYPE = 'PDF'

UPDATE  PDF
   SET  PDF.Description = MISC.Description
  FROM  @DB1 PDF
  JOIN  @DB1 MISC ON MISC.ID = PDF.ID
                 AND MISC.TYPE = 'MISC'
 WHERE  PDF.TYPE = 'PDF'

SELECT  *
  FROM  @DB1
 WHERE  TYPE = 'PDF'
```

As a note, in the future it helps if you can include some sample data for other readers to work with.  The way I created a table structure and populated it with some test data is a basic example of how this can be done.

If you find that an answer is useful and correct then don't forget to mark it as such and upvote.  That will help other users know what has worked.  That applies across the site in general not just your own questions.